# Is there a way to disable in Twilio that I can make an outbound call with unverified numbers?

Tags: twilio

Is there a way to disable in Twilio so that I can make an outbound call with unverified numbers?

I'm trying to set up some kind of integration with Twilio, Fusionpbx, and Zoho CRM and this is where I get stuck: I need to disable the feature to only allow outbound calls from verified numbers.

Answer (score 0):

there isn't a way to disable this feature. You can Verify CallerID's, so Twilio can verify you own a particular number, and therefore can advertise it in outbound CallerID. You can find more information, here:

[Adding a Verified Phone Number or Caller ID with Twilio](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180048-Adding-a-Verified-Phone-Number-or-Caller-ID-with-Twilio)